# Weyl constructions for finite groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, young-tableaux

Let $G$ be a finite group.

Is there a complex finite dimensional irreducible representation $V$ such that all irreducible ones are submodules of $V^{\otimes n}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

If not, what's the smallest group $G$ for this to fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a nice exercise in character theory to show that for $G$ a finite group and $V$ a representation, every irreducible representation occurs in $V^{\otimes n}$ for some $n$ iff $V$ is faithful (faithfulness is obviously necessary and sufficiency is the interesting direction).

So your question is equivalent to asking when $G$ has a faithful irreducible representation. A necessary condition, by Schur's lemma, is that the center $Z(G)$ must be cyclic (since it embeds into $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$), so $C_2 \times C_2$ (the smallest non-cyclic group) is the smallest counterexample.

**Edit:** Regarding the nice exercise above, here is the argument I had in mind.

> **Proposition:** Let $G$ be a finite group and $V$ a faithful finite-dimensional representation of it. Then every irreducible representation occurs in $V^{\otimes n}$ for some $n$.

*Proof.* Let $W$ be some irreducible and consider the characters $\chi_W, \chi_V$. We want to show that

$$\langle \chi_W, \chi_V^n \rangle = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \overline{\chi_W}(g) \chi_V(g)^n$$

is nonzero for some $n$. The idea of this proof is to consider what happens to this sum when $n$ is large: it's dominated by the terms where $|\chi_V(g)|$ is largest and all the other terms exponentially decay in comparison. Using the fact that $\chi_V(g)$ is the sum of the eigenvalues of $\rho_V(g)$, which are roots of unity, $|\chi_V(g)|$ has maximum value $\dim V$ and takes this maximum value iff all the eigenvalues of $\rho_V(g)$ are the same iff $\rho_V(g)$ is a scalar multiple of the identity (and the scalar must be some root of unity).

In the simplest case the only $g$ with this property is the identity; this happens, for example, in David Speyer's answer explaining a version of this proof in response to [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18194/faithful-representations-and-tensor-powers) because he added a copy of the trivial representation. In that case we get that the sum above is asymptotically $\frac{(\dim V)^n}{|G|} + O(c^n)$ where $|c| < \dim V$ and hence must be eventually positive, and with a little more effort we could give an upper bound on the smallest $n$ at which this occurs.

Instead of doing that we can just restrict our attention to the values of $n$ such that if $\rho_V(g)$ is a scalar multiple of the identity then $\rho_V(g)^n$ is the identity (at worst this means restricting our attention to $|G| \mid n$). If there are $k$ different elements of $g$ acting by a scalar then we get, for these restricted values of $n$, that the sum above is asymptotically $k \frac{(\dim V)^n}{|G|} + O(c^n)$ where $|c| < \dim V$, and again the conclusion follows. $\Box$

Less analytic and more algebraic arguments are possible that would generalize, for example, to fields of characteristic $0$. This argument has the benefit of generalizing, with some modification, to the case that $G$ is a compact group (although we need to consider irreducibles in $V^{\otimes n} \otimes (V^{\ast})^{\otimes m}$ in this case), as I learned from David Speyer on MO [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58633/does-every-irreducible-representation-of-a-compact-group-occur-in-tensor-products/58644#58644).

Comment: For a complete description of finite groups admitting an irreducible complex representation see the accepted answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57129/which-finite-groups-have-faithful-complex-irreducible-representations)

Comment: Interesting. Does a stronger statement hold, that the rank of $G$ coincide with the rank of $Rep(G)$? By rank of $G$ I mean the minimal number $r$ such that there exists $X=\{g_1 \ldots g_r\} \subseteq G$ such that $X$ generates $G$. By rank of $Rep(G)$ I mean the minimal number $s$ such that there exists $Y = \{V_1 \ldots V_s : simple\}$ such that $Rep(G)$ is the Karoubi completion of $Gen_\otimes(Y)$?

Comment: @Student: the rank of $\text{Rep}(G)$ in that sense is equal to $1$ for any $G$ with a faithful irreducible representation and in particular for any finite simple group, but a finite simple group has rank $1$ in the sense of being generated by one element iff it's cyclic. So e.g. $A_5$ is a counterexample. But the two agree if $G$ is finite abelian, because in that case the rank of $\text{Rep}(G)$ is the rank of the Pontryagin dual of $G$, which is (noncanonically) isomorphic to $G$.

Comment: Based on that $G$ and $Rep(G)$ are "the same", I'm hoping to depict their dimensions, in any sense. For the dimension in this context, $socle(G)$ seems to be the right thing to look at. Indeed, as given in @MoisheKohan 's link, $G$ has an irreducible faithful representation iff $socle(G)$ is a conjugacy class of **one** element! I wonder if this generalizes to larger numbers. Namely, re-defining the rank $r$ of $G$ to be the minimal number of elements in $socle(G)$ that conjugatingly generate $socle(G)$, does it coincides with $rank(Rep(G))$?

Comment: @Student: I don’t know anything about the socle so I can’t comment. That seems worth posting as a new question.

Comment: I should admit I cannot come up with a proof for sufficiency by myself. However, I found some [nice answers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18194/faithful-representations-and-tensor-powers) with the aid the the keyword "faithful representation". A stronger version can be found in [this thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10126/reference-for-this-theorem-in-representation-theory). Thank you.

Comment: @Student: I think most of those proofs (except David's) make this result seem more complicated and harder than it is. I'll edit with the argument I had in mind.

Comment: David's proof is nice and elementary, but it's pretty clever and uses (easy) analysis.. it's more than what I asked but I'd also hope for a purely algebraic proof.

Comment: @Student: there's a purely algebraic proof using Vandermonde determinants, which is alluded to in that MO thread. Is that enough of a hint or should I edit with the details? More-or-less-equivalently the result can be phrased using an easy finite version of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: No worries @QiaochuYuan! Thanks for all of your help. I will think for a while before I ask my next question (about rank).